# Show all tables within given MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to show all tables within a given MySQL database with php.
I'm very new to all this though and can't find a solution for it. Keeps giving an error 'no found file or directory'.

Anyone who can point out my mistakes here please?
Much appreciated!

```
<?php include "../inc/dbinfo.inc"; ?>
<html>
<body>
<h2>LIST TABLES FROM DATABASE</h2>
<?php

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection with the database failed: </br>" . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connection established with the database! </br>";

// SQL to show tables

$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM paperlessdb";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
    echo "Database error, could not list tables.\n</br>";
    echo 'MySQL error: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "- {$row[0]}\n </br>";
}

mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

Comment: Yes well, keep digging the graveyard of legacy code. `mysql_query()` dates back from 1995 and is not compatible with `mysqli`. And that error of yours: "no found file or directory", do you see that in this code? I don't, meaning you jumped to the wrong conclusion that this code causes it.

Comment: Are you certain of the path for your `dbinfo.inc` file?  That seems to be the only file that is being accessed?

Comment: Ok, so we have posibly 3 reason why this can break, mixed mysql and mysqli, a error for a missing file and a quey that can be changed. Pick one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make up your mind, either use [mysqli](/questions/tagged/mysqli) procedural or object orientated. Not a combination of both because its confusing. To avoid that all together use [pdo](/questions/tagged/pdo) instead.

Now properly connect to the database, you can select the database when connecting to it automatically:

```
const DB_DATABASE = 'paperlessdb';

$conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection with the database failed: </br>" . $conn->connect_error);
}

if($result = $conn->query('SHOW TABLES')){
  while($row = $conn->fetch_array($result)){
    $tables[] = $row[0];
  }
}

print_r($tables);
```

Comment: This looks to me like the most proper and clean answer. My answer looks more like a patch. Kudo to you.

Answer (score 2):

You are using [mysqli](/questions/tagged/mysqli) to connect to the database but use the depreciated [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) to query the database.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);

$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){}

mysql_free_result($result);
```

You should use [`mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) and [`mysqli_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) instead.

It'a a bit more complex but mysql is decrecated and remove as PHP 7 so no choice to jump ahead. Check out PDO ass well. I personally go for [mysqli](/questions/tagged/mysqli) but most say [pdo](/questions/tagged/pdo) is more intuitive.

It should look more something like:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if(!$result){
  die('MySQL error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "- {$row[0]}\n </br>";
}
```

Comment: That doesn'T help the fact taht you have a missing file but it will most likely fail there too.

Comment: Didn't even know there was a difference between all of that. Lot's to learn! But determination will get us there at some point. Thanks for pointing me in the correct direction! Much appreciated.

Comment: Learning curve :). Seriously, since you are there you should study mysqli prepared-statement or PDO to make your life easier (ok i meant safer). Takes a while to wrap your head around it but it's mandatory in my book. Keep it up.

Comment: Worked flawless with your code snippet. Strange that suddenly the file isn't missing anymore due to that change.

Comment: this ned to be changed too, i missed it : echo 'MySQL error: ' . mysql_error(); will edit snippet.

Comment: You should consider Xorilfelse answer below as he mention a good point about :  "either use mysqli procedural or OOP".  My code is a working patch but i think his code should be a more proper and clean way of doing this and you can take example on it.

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping me out. I learned a lot in under five minutes. Belgian beers for everyone if you find a way to hand me over your address. I'm serious about that.

Comment: I'm always in for some Duvel, @Louis, there is always an edit button. Approach the issue at hand, mysql not compatible with mysqli and you get my upvote.

Comment: There, fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Use below query,

```
$sql = "SELECT table_name
           FROM information_schema.tables
        WHERE table_schema = 'paperlessdb'";
```

We are fetching the data from information_schema db which stores the meta data about our database.

Comment: Correct sql, missing the fact that the query fails to be executed.

Comment: @Xorifelse I didn't get you.

Comment: That's the query i use to get info about the table too, but OP said something about a missing file or folder, and he is mixing up mysql and mysqli. So i think @Xorifelse means you have the good query, but still lack the 2 other reason why OP is scrachting his head.

Comment: @Abhishekgurjar take a look at the code in the question, `mysqli_connect()` ~> `mysql_query()`, the two don't mix.